Baseline covariates with age as time scale in survival analysis
I’m looking for the correct way to incorporate baseline information in a survival analysis when using age as the time scale (or confirmation that what I'm saying in the following is correct).
Clearly, if you set the origin as birth then covariate information is not going to be available at that time. So, an alternative might be to decide on a minimum age of interest - e.g. 20 years, setting that as the origin and then having delayed entry and left-truncation for anyone entering the study older than that.
I have two questions relating to this:

This relies on having covariate information for everyone at the age of 20, right? i.e. if someone enters the study at 26 it's incorrect to use the covariate values at that age as baseline? Is there anything you can do if that's all you have?
Is it appropriate/necessary to centre everyone's age? i.e. subtract 20 from each age so that the 'new' baseline is zero?

As a related aside, I also wonder the implications are for propensity score matching when using age as the time scale.
Thanks,
